# Checking whether obj.prop.innerprop.yetAnotherInnerProp is defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any easy way to check whether a deeply nested object is defined? For example, can i do something like

```
typeof obj.prop.innerprop.yetAnotherInnerProp === 'undefined'
```

such that it should return true in case any of the inner objects are undefined.

In this case, we know for sure that `obj` is defined, but not sure whether `prop`, `innerprop` or `yetAnotherInnerProp` is defined. My function needs the value of `yetAnotherInnerProp`, but at runtime the root `obj` can have a structure that matches the one shown above, or it could have a different structure like `obj.diffprop.diffinner`. I want to check if `yetAnotherInnerProp` exists.

I know I could do something like,

```
if(obj.hasOwnProperty('prop')
  if(obj.prop.hasOwnProperty('innerprop')
    if(obj.prop.innerprop.hasOwnProperty('yetAnotherInnerProp')
     value = obj.prop.innerprop.yetAnotherInnerProp
```

But I wanted to know if there's an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Nope. Different _methods_ of achieving, but must check each along the way. Otherwise will throw.

Comment: Yeah I could use `try...catch` to achieve this too, but I was just wondering if there's an easier _shorthand_ way to do this..